# Python: order of dictionary initialization

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `d` that I'd like to copy shallowly and then change some of its contents. I noticed that if I write the changed property first, it'll get overwritten. If I write it last, it persists:

```
>>> d = {1: 1, 2: 2}
{1: 1, 2: 2}
>>> d1 = {1: 11, **d}
{1: 1, 2: 2}
>>> d2 = {**d, 1: 11}
{1: 11, 2: 2}
```

However, I know the order in a dictionary isn't reliable. Can I assume that in `{**d, 1: 11}`, `d[1]` definitely gets overwritten by the updated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the section on [dictionary displays](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) in the [Python language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html) (my italics):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary: each key object is used as a key into the dictionary to store the corresponding datum. *This means that you can specify the same key multiple times in the key/datum list, and the final dictionary’s value for that key will be the last one given.*

> A double asterisk ** denotes dictionary unpacking. Its operand must be a mapping. Each mapping item is added to the new dictionary. *Later values replace values already set by earlier key/datum pairs and earlier dictionary unpackings.*

Unless I’m missing something, this seems to guarantee that later values overwrite earlier ones.

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.6 onwards, the standard dict type maintains insertion order by default.

In this case, later occurrences overwrite previous ones.

So, if you say `d1 = {1: 11, **d}`, the value of the `1` would be updated with new value, and if you say `d2 = {**d, 1: 11}`, the value of `1` in `d` would be updated with `1: 11`.

So yes! You can be sure that `d[1]` gets overwritten by the updated value.